# Печать из RichEdit

Tags: delphi, vcl

Есть код печати из RichEdit

```
procedure TfrmMain.PrintRichEdit(RichEdit: TRichEdit; const Caption: string; const PrinterMargin: Integer);
var
  PrinterHeight, PrinterWidth: Integer;
  LogPixels, PrinterTopLeft: TPoint;
  PageRect: TRect;
  Handle: HDC;
begin
  Handle := Printer.Handle;
  LogPixels := Point(GetDeviceCaps(Handle, LOGPIXELSX),
  GetDeviceCaps(Handle, LOGPIXELSY));
  PrinterTopLeft := Point(GetDeviceCaps(Handle, PHYSICALOFFSETX),
  GetDeviceCaps(Handle, PHYSICALOFFSETY));
  PrinterWidth := Printer.PageWidth;
  PrinterHeight := Printer.PageHeight;
  PageRect.Left := Max(0, Round(PrinterMargin*LogPixels.X / 25.4)- PrinterTopLeft.X);
  PageRect.Top := Max(0, Round(PrinterMargin*LogPixels.Y / 25.4) - PrinterTopLeft.Y);
  PageRect.Right := PrinterWidth-PageRect.Left;
  PageRect.Bottom := PrinterHeight-PageRect.Top;
  if (PageRect.Left >= PageRect.Right) or (PageRect.Top >= PageRect.Bottom) then
     PageRect := Rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
  RichEdit.PageRect := PageRect;
  RichEdit.Print(Caption);
end;
```

Но мне нужно еще в конце листа печатать дату и номер. Можно ли это сделать?

Comment: Впечатать их в сам код rtf?

Comment: ну что то типа нумерации листов только с моими данными